# Reference XtraReport in Dotnet Core application

Tags: devexpress, .net-core

I would like to create a **dotnet core console application** that should create pdf report using DevExpress **XtraReport**.

How can I reference the *devexpress dll* in my *csproj*?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**:
the project targets **net462**

This is my *csproj*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot/" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Properties/**">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="tempkey.rsa">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

XtraReports does support the dotnet core platform starting with v18.1.
https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/reporting/archive/2018/04/26/reporting-net-core-support-ctp-v18-1.aspx

https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/119717/create-end-user-reporting-applications/web-reporting/aspnet-core-reporting

Comment: Even if you target net462?

Comment: .net core application can target .net core 1 , net core 1.1 and net core 2. not the net462

Comment: I target <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework> because of I'm using Entity Framework 6 (core does not support Oracle).
I put my csproj in the OP

Comment: so this is not the dotnet core. it is aspnet core.

Comment: you right, sorry. So it is possible to reference XtraReport?

Comment: in the visual studio press on the "add reference.." and select needed dlls.

Comment: vscode is not supports the full dotnet, but dotnet core only. afaik, even if you start the aspnet core project in the vscode, it will be run under the dotnet core platform.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this - [Reporting support for .Net core](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T511815/reporting-support-for-net-core)

> It's hard to speak about possible estimates here as NET Core 2.0 does
>   not support System.Drawing, Sörnt. Right now, everything that is
>   available in .NET Standard 2.0 is a few drawing primitives, that's all
>   (see diff). On the other hand, implementing a custom drawing library
>   that would work for any possible target .NET platform is a very
>   complex task — I'd say it's just as hard as doing a new reporting
>   engine from scratch. Yes, there are some alternatives for drawing
>   (e.g., Mono's gdipluslib), but they have a lot of compatibility issues
>   we need to deal with, not to mention that some areas (like the actual
>   printing) are not covered at all. Of course, being compatible with the
>   .NET Standard is something is that we look forward to, but there are
>   still missing pieces our engine heavily relies on. Needless to say,
>   the .NET Core development is moving really fast comparing to the
>   legacy .NET Framework, so it's highly possible that we'll see more and
>   more features / APIs provided by the corefx team very soon.

It is not yet supported in .net core apps. There may be some workaround to use in asp.net core applications.. See below reference links.

**References:**
[XtraReports in .NET Core](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T400381/xtrareports-in-net-core)
[XtraReports for ASP.NET Core](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T464959/xtrareports-for-asp-net-core)
[Reporting support for .Net core](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T531959/reporting-support-for-net-core)